# invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidAppser\ACTSelfCare\res layouxxhdpi

Tags: android

android multi screen support.when i am creating a second 2nd layout folder with folder name lauoytxxhdpi i am getting following error.

invalid resource directory name: C:\AndroidAppser\ACTSelfCare\res layouxxhdpi

Comment: '-' is not a valid resource name character.error when i am creating a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

C:\AndroidAppser\ACTSelfCare\res\layout-xxhdpi

Comment: but when i am creating a new folder i am getting follwing error.

Comment: '-' is not a valid resource name character

Comment: 1)which tool you are using? eclipse or Android Studio?
2)from where you are creating folder. i) from tool or 2)windows?

Comment: i am using eclipse.windows

Comment: Create folder from eclipse and refresh project..by closing and opening again..

And if possible move to Android  Studio . which is officially supported by google..